# Can't upload image on FTP with AngularJS and PHP. Returns 403

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ftp

I want to upload an image to a FTP using AngularJS and PHP. I've tried a two solutions I found here, using AngularJS's $http service, and using vanilla JS XMLHttpRequest object. Both of them returns 403.

I then changed the FTP folder permission to 777 but got the same result.

I figured it needed authentication, so I thought I'd use PHP to send the file, but I can't figure how to send the File object to PHP. And to be honest I'm not even sure this makes sense.

Can anyone help me?

Here goes my code:

First I get the File object like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = document.querySelector("input[type='file']").files[0];
formData.append("file", file);
```

Then I use either AngularJS or vanilla.

AngularJS solution:

```
$http.post('./img', formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
}).then(/* promise handler */)
```

Vanilla solution:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "./img", true);
xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

I've also tried this solution:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "php_file.php", true);
xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

I thought I'd post the File object to PHP and use it to upload it with credentials, but when I "print_r($_FILES)" it gives me an empty object.

UPDATE: I made it work with "send File object to PHP" approach, I guess I wasn't logging the output correctly so I thought it wasn't doing anything. After posting to a PHP file I just used the move_uploaded_file() function and didn't have to authenticate FTP or anything, so I still don't understand why I get 403 with the other approaches.

Any ideias?

Thanks!

Comment: You have checked the api if its sending the intended data?

Comment: I don't know how to do exactly what you're suggesting, but when I "console.dir(formData)" it only shows the append method. It seems it's not appending correctly or else I'd get the other methods (described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData#Methods)), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP method to send a file is PUT, not POST. 
Then, you need to specify that you want to use FTP protocol by writing the URL ftp://mywebsite.com/img. If you don't do this, you are sending a POST request to ./img, that seems to be forbidden on with your HTTP server.